# Spring Security allowing alternative to username

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

I'm using Spring security 3.x. In my login page, there is an additional field that the user would scan an ID card to populate. If they do this, the username is not required (it is looked up against the ID scanned), but the password still is.

The problem is that the username is required by my custom `AuthenticationProvider`.  The ID is captured in a filter before this (`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`).  I don't know how to connect them so my `AuthProvider` knows it doesn't require username (and also, how does it get the ID at this point since it is passed an Authentication object?).

Comment: I believe I *may* have stumbled upon the answer here:
[link](http://hussainpithawala.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/extending-spring-security/)
The key is, instead of calling super.attemptAuthentication(req, resp) at the end of my filter to have Sprind deal with username/password, get the username/password/id myself, create an auth token using them, and pass it to the authentication manager.
Still testing...

Answer (score 1):

You might need a special kind of Authentication interface that is not a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and hence doesn't require the username and password both.
Then your AuthenticationProcessingFilter/AuthenticationProvider may create one of them.
Have a look at spring-cas-client and [CasAuthenticationToken](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/cas/authentication/CasAuthenticationToken.html) as an example.

Comment: Yup, I extended UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken to add the additional field required.  The Filter/Provider now instantiates my custom token with the added field, and as well the filter manually does the retrievals on username/password, effectively bypassing any Spring validation checks on them.

Answer (score 0):

The filter I was extending was FORM_LOGIN_FILTER, which is correct, however I needed to perform all the retrievals (j_username, j_password) here and call the authentication manager manually, instead of calling the super() method which passes the retrievals and auth manager calls to Spring.  This also required extending the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. Once I do this, they are connected.